# Make all hyperlinks execute click action on mouse keydown in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the standard browser behavior in a web app where a mousedown click would cause the click action to happen before the button is released. I want this for all the hyperlinks in an app.
Is there a simple way to accomplish this in jQuery? 
I am not looking for a solution to change every link individually. It should be a global event handler which works in current and future links.

**Example:**
in Yahoo Mail, as soon as you click on a tab, that tab gets focus. It happens before the button is released.

There's a requirement to mimic this behavior for hyper links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly and you want to override the default link behavior, something like this should work:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").bind({ 
        click: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        mouseenter: function(){
            window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
        } 
    });
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H2L4D/1/

Comment: It's on mousedown not when hovering. Also it needs to work on dynamically created links so I used on() (jQuery 1.7+) or live(). http://jsfiddle.net/H2L4D/3/

Answer (score 0):

You need http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

```
$('a').mousedown(function() {
  alert('Handler for .mousedown() called.');
});
```

Comment: What's the action to do the default click?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like it to apply to all hyperlinks over the lifetime of the page, even dynamically-created ones, you'll want something like this:

```
$('a').live('mousedown', function(evt)
{
   // this stops the default behaviour of the event
   evt.preventDefault() 

   // This changes the location of the page to the href value of the element you clicked
   window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");

});
```

Comment: What's the action to do the default click? I don't have custom logic.

Comment: Ah.  Right.  You want to prevent the default link behaviour and then follow the link anyway.  Someone has already replied with how to do this for a .bind().  I'll edit my original response to include it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').unbind('click');

$('a').bind('mousedown', function() {
  //alert('mousedown happened');
});
```

Comment: What's the action to do the default click?

Comment: bind() doesn't take care of dynamically created links.